# Ionic fab button is not displaying properly in App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm trying to include fab-buttons  [(FAB button in the link)](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/button/Button/) in my app homepage. but it just displays normal button square buttons. could you please help identify.

**My HTML;**

```
<ion-content>
       <a ng-repeat="area in areaArray | orderBy: 'name'" class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
            <img ng-src={{area["image"]}} ui-sref="tabs.projects({area:area['name']})">
            <h2>{{ area["name"]}}</h2>
      <button class="button button-fab-center button-balanced" ui-sref="tabs.projects({area:area['name'], Project_Status:'Green'})">
                     {{ area["active"]}}</i>
         </button>
         <button class="button button-fab-center button-assertive" ui-sref="tabs.projects({area:area['name'], Project_Status:'Red'})">
                      {{ area["alert"]}}</i>
          </button>
          <button class="button button-fab-center button-energized" ui-sref="tabs.projects({area:area['name'], Project_Status:'Amber'})">
                     {{ area["Amber"]}}</i>
         </button>
     </a>
</ion-content>
```

This is my output:

[image: This is my output]

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problems but is easy to solve, dont worry :)

You just need this to have a FAB button

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
```

**IMPORTANT** You have to upgrade the ionic version at least to 2.0.0-rc0 and you will see your beautiful FAB button :)

Docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/fab/FabButton/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-fab slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

> Find this in the official documentation. try this [fab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab)
> check link for more